# TDD and MVC 3, Testing Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, tdd

I am trying to learn how to unit test and work with MVC 3 and I am getting stuck on the problem of How do I test two models. Here is the code

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IRepository _repository;

    public  HomeController(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_repository.GetAllGenres());
    }    
}

public interface IRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Genre> GetAllGenres();
    IEnumerable<Album> GetTopAlbums(int count);
}
```

and assume this is my Unit Testing

```
[TestFixture]
class HomeControllerTests
{
    [Test]
    public  void Test1()
    {                
        //Arrange
        var controller = new HomeController(new InMemoryRepository());
        var result = (ViewResult) controller.Index();

        Assert.AreEqual(10,((IEnumerable<Genre>)result.ViewData.Model).Count());
    }

    [Test]
    public  void Test2()
    {
        var controller = new HomeController(new InMemoryRepository());
        var result = (ViewResult) controller.Index();
        //I Want to be able to do something like this
        Assert.AreEqual(5,result.ViewData.Model.GetTopAlbums(5).Count);
    }
}
```

Now my question is How exactly do I go about making something like I want work. Or do I create a ChildActionOnly Method that is responsible for returning the Top Albums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using a mocking framework to assist with you tests? For example you could make use of mock on your GetTopAlbums call. My preference is [moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) but there are several great mocking frameworks to choose from.

Note, this is a pretty simple example but you could easily create a test helper to generate a list with your expected number of albums:

```
[Test]
public void Index_Get_Should_Lookup_Top_Albums_And_Return_Index_View()
{
    // arrange
    var expectModel = new List<Album>
                            {
                                new Album{Artist= "joe", Tracks = 16},
                                new Album{Artist= "doe", Tracks = 23},
                            };

    _repository.Setup(x => x.GetTopContacts(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(expectModel);

    var controller = new HomeController(_repository.Object);

    // act
    var result = controller.TopContacts();
    var model = result.ViewData.Model as IEnumerable<Album>;

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(2, model.Count());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a very good solution for you. See the below two blog posts:

> [Generic Repository Pattern - Entity Framework, ASP.NET MVC and Unit
>   Testing Triangle](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle)
>
> [How to Work With Generic Repositories on ASP.NET MVC and Unit Testing
>   Them By Mocking](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/how-to-work-with-generic-repositories-on-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-them-by-mocking)

Basically, it is what @Jesse already suggested but those two posts also has some other features there which might be helpful for you.